# No Ethernet even in macOS Recovery mode

Tags: network, catalina, imac, ethernet

Catalina 10.5.7 on an iMac 27" 2020.

From one day to another the Ethernet connection to the router has stopped. It went from a green to a red dot.
Whatever I try the message stays always the same:
Either the cable for Ethernet is not plugged in or the device at the other end is not responding.

Checked the cable with a MacBook, no problem.

Checked all ports in the router with a MacBook, no problem.

Installed a "clean copy" of Catalina on an external drive and booted the iMac from the external drive: no Ethernet.

BUT: Booting a Macbook from the same external drive: Ethernet is alive

Tried also this: I started up from macOS Recovery on the iMac, using Recovery > MacOS Utilities > Get Help Online: Ethernet is not working there either. Only WiFi.

Conclusion:
damaged ethernet port on the iMac just like this?

Or is there a way to make Ethernet working again?
What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to your tests and observations it sounds like the Ethernet port in the iMac is physically damaged.

This could happen due to some sort of electrical issue such as a transient or similar spike of electricity. Perhaps it was lightning weather around the time it happened - perhaps it was a malfunction in the router - perhaps it was just tired hardware in the iMac.

Comment: I have been using also Apple Diagnostics (former Apple Hardware Test). The result was: No errors. What then is this diagnostic tool good for?

Comment: If the issue is with the physical socket, then unless it runs actual tests over a connected link [which requires a special loopback ethernet plug], it won't be able to see that.

Comment: Does replacing the ethernet port on this mac means to change the motherboard?

Comment: Yes, most likely - at least if you do an official repair. You could consider connecting your ethernet through other means - for example a Thunderbolt ethernet adapter or a USB-ethernet adapter.